# What is the right way to serialize data for django?

Tags: json, django

I need to build a database for Django by parsing various config files (I am writing a builder for a project that allows modules to just be dropped in).

I was going to manually just build an array of dictionaries and write that out to json so I could do

```
python manage loaddata myjson.json
```

But that seems wrong. And error prone. Is there a more 'right' way to do this?

TLDR: How do I build a database for Django on the fly?

Comment: Try exploring [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels).